# Use set function from custom hooks inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I created a custom hook that maintain state in a certain type based on data in a different type like this:

```
import { useState, useRef, Dispatch } from 'react';

function useBackedState<TData, TBacking>(initialData: TBacking, converter: (backing: TBacking) => TData):
[
  state: TData,
  getBackingData: () => TBacking,
  setData: Dispatch<TBacking>
] {

  const ref = useRef(initialData);
  const [state, setState] = useState(converter(initialData));

  const setData: Dispatch<TBacking> = (val: TBacking) => {
    ref.current = val;
    setState(converter(val));
  };

  return [
    state,
    () => ref.current,
    setData
  ];
}

export default useBackedState;
```

However, I have problems when I call on `setData` inside a `useEffect` hook.

For example, I tested it in this component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import useBackedState from './hooks/useBackedState';

function Component() {

  const [data, backing, setData] = useBackedState<string, string[]>(
    [],
    (arr) => arr.join('');
  );
  
  const [somethingElse, setSomethingElse] = useState('a');
  
  useEffect(() => {

    setSomethingElse('b');
  
    setData(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{data}</p>
      ... some more rendering
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want `useEffect` to only run once at the start, so I provided an empty array of dependencies. However, although the app works, I get this warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setData'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array

If I do add `setData` as a dependency, the entire app goes into an infinite loop of refresh and I get this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

I am not required to add the `setSomethingElse` as a dependency to `useEffect`. Why am I required to add `setData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All state and prop values that get referenced inside a hook should have that value in the dependency array - *so the argument goes*. If you agree and wish to satisfy the linter, here, it's easy - just memoize the functions returned from the custom hook (which is often a good practice anyway, especially when exhaustive-deps is being used).

```
const setData: Dispatch<TBacking> = useCallback((val: TBacking) => {
    ref.current = val;
    setState(converter(val));
}, [setState, converter]);
```

> I am not required to add the setSomethingElse as a dependency to useEffect

The linter can see that `setSomethingElse` comes *directly* from a state setter function declared in the same component, and thus definitely won't ever change, and so doesn't need to be in the dependency array.